# Simple elif statement

Tags: python, if-statement

When I run this code it always goes to the `else`. Even when I choose 1, 2, or 3. How can I achieve a proper `if, elif else` statement?

```
def main():
    name = input("What is your name?")
    print("Hello", name)
    choice = int
    choice = 0
    choice = input("Please choose a number from the following options: \n 1. Paper \n 2. Rock \n 3. Scissors")
    print (choice)

    if choice == 1:
        print ('You chose number 1')
    elif choice == 2:
        print ('You chose number 2')
    elif choice == 3:
        print ('You chose number 3')
    else:
        print ('Invalid Entry Mush')
    return

main()
```

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: Please tag as Python. There are some unnecessary lines of code in your script, but the problem is the input is a string and not an integer. wrap the numbers in the conditions with quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can put your if statements between quotes: ex: if choice == "1" print("nr 1") elif choice == "2" so on ..

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string. You will need to cast it to an int so that your elif options that check for ints are triggered:

```
choice = int(input("Please choose a number from the following options: \n 1. Paper \n 2. Rock \n 3. Scissors"))
```

By the way the two lines before that one are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank a lot for taking the time to reply! Very helpful :-)

Comment: No problem! Be sure to accept answer if your question has been resolved ;)